# can i have 3 sharedpreferences files and how to read each one

Tags: android

I am having three files in xml folder

```
beginning_text.xml
preferences.xml
caller.xml
```

All three files are used as SharedPreferences file

Can i use all three files as

```
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.sms_beginning_text, false);
       addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.sms_beginning_text);

PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preferences, false);
       addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.caller, false);
       addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.caller);
```

and then reading it like:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

or how can i read and save 3 different files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the names of your preference files and while retriving the preferences, mention the name of that file which you want to access in getSharedPreferences().

Here I declare two file names : PrefFile and PrefFileNEW; then I pass the respective names to the getSharedPreference() while retrieving the preferences.

```
public static final String PREF_FILE_NAME = "PrefFile";
public static final String PREF_FILE_NAME_NEW = "PrefFileNEW";
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
{
//access your preferences here
}

SharedPreferences preferences_new = getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME_NEW, MODE_PRIVATE);

{
//access your preferences_new here
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: @mbrc : Sorry my friend, but I have seen the true usage of PreferenceActivity and hence have always used a simple Activity in my code and then use getSharedPrefs(). So, I really have no idea about setDefaultValues. But, I am sure you can achieve everything that you are implementing in your PreferenceActivity through my code also. :)